# Adding a weak_ptr scenario

Tags: c++11

I am trying to come up with a simple example of when a shared_ptr would be used and when a unique or a weak pointer will be used. Trying to better understand smart pointers.
In my case. I came up with a Recipe scenario. A recipe will have ingredients(eggs,meat) which it will own(`unique_ptr`) and then a recipe is passed to a burner. The same recipe can be cooked on multiple burners (hence) a `shared_ptr`. This shows the basic

```
class Recipe {
public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr> ingrediants;
    void addIngrediant(std::unique_ptr<Ingrediants> i){
        ingrediants.push_back(std::move(i));
    }
};

class Burner {
public:
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Recipe>> recipes;
   void addRecipe(const std::shared_ptr<Recipe>& r) {
    recipes.emplace_back(r);
   }
}
```

In the above case I have managed to use a `shared_ptr` and a `unique_ptr`. Can someone help me come up with a situation and add a scenario on when I would use a `weak_ptr` ?

Comment: There's a cat in a box. You have a weak pointer to it. When you check the weak pointer you find out if the cat is alive or dead.

Comment: A callback, or event sink, subscribed to possibly multiple event sources. The source needs a way to obtain a sink pointer to call and notify of an event, but you don't want the subscription to keep the sink alive (e.g. it represents a window on the screen, and should be destroyed when the user clicks X button). So the source would keep a weak pointer to the sink.